# How to configure two way ssl communication between two weblogic server?

Tags: java

I am trying to do two way ssl communication. My server is deployed on one weblogic server and client on another. I have imported valid certificate at client side and trying to invoke webservice running on https. 
I have written simple servelet class which invoke webservice on https. I have set following properties in client code.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/opt/bea1/certificates/VDFNLimitedV01.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "XXXXX");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
```

When i compile and run stand alone simple client code through unix server it is running fine but when i deploy client on weblogic and hit thr url i am getting bad certificate exception. 
**Client side error**

```
   oled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer).
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1467)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1435)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1601)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1031)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:845)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:721)
            at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:607)
            at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$4.run(JaSSLEngine.java:118)
            at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
            at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:116)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:93)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:59)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.write(JSSEFilterImpl.java:391)
            at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEOutputStream.write(JSSESocket.java:78)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
            at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
            at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:162)
            at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:376)
            at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:842)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:289)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:138)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:284)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:246)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:197)
            at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:187)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:84)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSProvider.java:598)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:120)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:112)
            at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:83)
            at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
            at com.vodafone.main.TokenService.<init>(TokenService.java:49)
            at vodafone.TransactClient.getMessage(TransactClient.java:65)
            at vodafone.TransactClient.doGet(TransactClient.java:77)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

**Server Side Error:**

```
[Raw read]: length = 5>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <0000: 16 03 01 00 4D                                     ....M
[Raw read]: length = 77>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 00 42 00 40 49 59 42  ..........B.@IYB
0010: 09 08 EF 92 70 2E E7 49   E6 73 00 B0 33 7C A9 F0  ....p..I.s..3...
0020: 42 D1 3F F2 DA B9 80 FD   9E E8 15 21 C3 7E 42 A2  B.?........!..B.
0030: CF 1A 20 A0 17 ED B3 D6   3B 5C 68 1E 49 06 97 65  .. .....;\h.I..e
0040: 70 8A 40 03 C1 93 FB 3F   A9 26 B6 E9 67           p.@....?.&..g
ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 77>
**<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <*** Certificate chain>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <***>**
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', called closeOutbound()>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', closeOutboundInternal()>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <[Raw write]: length = 7>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2A                               ......*
ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', called closeOutbound()>
<Dec 12, 2012 3:06:54 PM UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', closeOutboundInternal()>
```

I am able to send client certificate when i run java code through unix box but not from weblogic. Can anybody plz help me with this?  How should i configure weblogic to act as ssl client?

Thanks, 
Pooja Kulkarni